# Strange units of measurement of heat transfer coefficient in Newton's cooling law

Tags: thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis, si-units

In my finite element software there is the following equation:

[image]

in the original Newton's cooling law h has the units $W/(m^2 K)$.
Why here it has the units $W/(m^3 K)$?

Comment: It must be a typo.

Comment: Hello @ChesterMiller the units are right. Also in other windows and in other releases of the software there are the same units.

Comment: Oh.  I didn't notice the equation at the top of the window.  Sorry.

Comment: $h_ext$ is not convective heat transfer coefficient. Your memory is correct and the terminology in the software is not. $h_ext$ is volumetric heat coefficient. $h_ext = h_c * a$ where $h_c$ is convective heat transfer coefficient and $a$ is the surface area per unit volume.

Comment: Hello @user115350 htrans and hc are different, in fact in software I can set hc=/=0 and htrans=0.

Comment: what's that soft?

Comment: Hello @HDE it's Comsol

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the heat source $Q$ is given in $W/m^3$.

Since $h=\frac{Q}{\Delta T}$ the units must be $W/(m^3 K)$.

Hope this helps.